# Pandas excel 3 level header transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

Having an excel sheet for sales by product by state by location as below

|  |  |  | New Jersey | New Jersey | California | California | California | California | New York | New York |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Willowbrook | Willowbrook | Great Mall | Great Mall | Westminster Mall | Westminster Mall | The Fulton Center | The Fulton Center |  |  |
| Transaction Date | Transaction Document | Partno | Qty | Value | Qty | Value | Qty | Value | Qty | Value | Total Qty | Total Value |
| 17/5/2022 | 8534 | P1 |  |  | 1 | 150.00 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 150.00 |
| 17/5/2022 | 8654 | P6 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 400.00 |  |  | 2 | 400.00 |
| 18/5/2022 | 3537 | P2 | 1 | 175.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 175.00 |
| 20/5/2022 | 2301 | P3 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 150.00 | 2 | 150.00 |
| 20/5/2022 | 2301 | P5 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 50.00 | 1 | 50.00 |

Need to change it to become as below

| Transaction Date | Transaction Document | Partno | Qty | Value | State | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17/5/2022 | 8534 | P1 | 1 | 150.00 | California | Great Mall |
| 17/5/2022 | 8654 | P6 | 2 | 400.00 | California | Westminster Mall |
| 18/5/2022 | 3537 | P2 | 1 | 175.00 | New Jersey | Willowbrook |
| 20/5/2022 | 2301 | P3 | 2 | 150.00 | New York | The Fulton Center |
| 20/5/2022 | 2301 | P5 | 1 | 50.00 | New York | The Fulton Center |

There are monthly reports like this so I was looking for a python function that uses pandas or any other library to be able to pass the files and transform it as above

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` and `print (df.index)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove last 2 columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), create columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=[0, 1, 2])

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('17/5/2022 ', 8534, 'P1 '),
            ('17/5/2022 ', 8654, 'P6 '),
            ('18/5/2022 ', 3537, 'P2 '),
            ('20/5/2022 ', 2301, 'P3 '),
            ('20/5/2022 ', 2301, 'P5 ')],
           )

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([(        'New Jersey ',        'Willowbrook ',         'Qty '),
            (        'New Jersey ',        'Willowbrook ',      ' Value '),
            (        'California ',         'Great Mall ',         'Qty '),
            (        'California ',         'Great Mall ',      ' Value '),
            (        'California ',   'Westminster Mall ',         'Qty '),
            (        'California ',   'Westminster Mall ',      ' Value '),
            (          'New York ',  'The Fulton Center ',         'Qty '),
            (          'New York ',  'The Fulton Center ',      ' Value '),
            ('Unnamed: 11_level_0', 'Unnamed: 11_level_1',   'Total Qty '),
            ('Unnamed: 12_level_0', 'Unnamed: 12_level_1', ' Total Value')],
           names=[' ', None, 'Transaction Date '])
```

---

```
df1 = (df.iloc[:, :-2]
         .rename_axis(columns=['State','Location', None],
                      index=['Transaction Date','Transaction Document','Partno'])
         .stack(level=[0,1])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Transaction Date  Transaction Document Partno        State  \
0       17/5/2022                   8534    P1   California    
1       17/5/2022                   8654    P6   California    
2       18/5/2022                   3537    P2   New Jersey    
3       20/5/2022                   2301    P3     New York    
4       20/5/2022                   2301    P5     New York    

             Location   Value   Qty   
0         Great Mall     150.0   1.0  
1   Westminster Mall     400.0   2.0  
2        Willowbrook     175.0   1.0  
3  The Fulton Center     150.0   2.0  
4  The Fulton Center      50.0   1.0
```

Comment: This actually almost worked but the 'Unnamed' cells got into the rows and mixed everything wrong, when I read the data its pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsx', header = [0,1,2]), am i doing something wrong

Comment: @Gojoe - Can you try `pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsx', header = [0,1,2], index_col=[0,1,2])` ?

Comment: @jezrael, you can add `df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=[0, 1, 2]).rename_axis(index=['Transaction Date', 'Transaction Document', 'Partno'], columns=['State', 'Location', 'Variable'])`